# What is the proper way to test 'create' controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, Rspec 2.9.0 and RspecRails 2.9.0. I would like to test the `create` controller action but I don't know how to make that the "right"/"proper" way. I "scaffolded" model, controller, view, ... files, so in those files I have the common code generated by Ruby on Rails generators; in my spec file I have:

```
it "assigns @article" do
  new_article = FactoryGirl.build(:article)
  Article.should_receive(:new).and_return(new_article)
  post :create
  assigns[:article].should eq(new_article)
end
```

Maybe, (*note*: the above code is almost the same as that I use to test the `new` controller action) *a better way to test `create` controller actions would be to pass some attribute value during the `post :create` action instead of proceed as I make above*, but I don't know how to make that and if it is the "right"/"proper" way to make things.

So, **what is the proper way to test 'create' controller actions?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
it "creates article" do 
  article_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article)
  expect { post :create, :article => article_params }.to change(Article, :count).by(1) 
end
```

Comment: Maybe you would say `... { post :create, :article => article_params }.to ...` instead of `... { post :create, article_params }.to ...`.

Answer (score 18):

I'm doing it this way:

```
describe "#create" do
  before { post :create, { "my_model"=> { "name"=>"name" } } }
  specify("should created one my_model") { change{ MyModel.count }.from(0).to(1) }
end
```

Aaron Sumner who recently wrote the book [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec](http://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec) have an [article at his blog](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html). Where he describes it like this:

```
describe "POST create" do
  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "creates a new contact" do
      expect{
        post :create, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:contact)
      }.to change(Contact,:count).by(1)
    end

    it "redirects to the new contact" do
      post :create, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:contact)
      response.should redirect_to Contact.last
    end
  end

  context "with invalid attributes" do
    it "does not save the new contact" do
      expect{
        post :create, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:invalid_contact)
      }.to_not change(Contact,:count)
    end

    it "re-renders the new method" do
      post :create, contact: Factory.attributes_for(:invalid_contact)
      response.should render_template :new
    end
  end 
end
```